# Manage Azure AD in React

Tags: reactjs, active-directory

Is it possible to manage (create and add users to groups, create groups) Azure active directory inside ReactJs? My React app is server-less using React Apollo.
If not, maybe it's possible to execute powershell scripts that perform commands inside the AD in ReactJs?